# Laravel HTTP Client not passing the data to API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-http-client

**Controller request where I'm passing from parameters to API:**

```
$response = Http::withOptions([
        'debug' => true,
        ])->post('https://starznets.com/api/login.php', [
        'dosubmit' => $request->dosubmit,
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => $request->password,
         ]);

     $body = $response->body();
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($body);
     die;
```

[image: Response of Request]

[image: Response on Postmaster]

Comment: Is `starznets.com` yours? Looks like your login calls your own login. The `About to connect...` looks like the debug ouput you set `'debug' => true`. And the json at the end is your `print_r($body);` given that `$body` is just a string and not an arrray. And postmaster is going to another URL or is ignoring the first output and just shows the json

Comment: I'm sending request from starznets.com to starznetsglobal.com. Here in code just enter url as example.